# High usage of swap sapce

Tags: ram, swap, memory-usage, memory-leak

My swap space has a high usage while i've set `swappiness` value to 10.

```
root@srv35298:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2012       1941         70          0          0        110
-/+ buffers/cache:       1830        182
Swap:         1023        757        266
```

How can I force it to reduce usage of swap space?

Comment: You can't. Swap space is used when there is no more available physical RAM memory.  Since you only have 70mb of RAM left, it starts using the swap. So, if I were you, I'd find a way to get more RAM. Also, what are you doing on it? I have 6gb of RAM on my laptop, and I rarely use 2gb!

Comment: It's my server and all of my tasks like celery or database queries should be done in the RAM.